# Unbinding a jQuery listener from a subset of elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I'm using Zurb Foundation tooltips (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html). I'd like to customize their behavior slightly. They make use of a `mouseover` event listener on the source element to create the tooltip (on the first call) and then fade it in. What I'm attempting to do is to have jQuery select a subset of the tooltip sources on the page, remove just their mouseover listeners, and bind new ones that will let the tooltip stay there for a second before disappearing after the mouse has been moved away.

Here's the tricky part. Zurb binds its listener as such:

`$('body.off-canvas').on('mouseenter', '.has-tooltip', ...);`

The following will successfully remove this listener, as expected:

`$('body.off-canvas').off('mouseenter', '.has-tooltip');`

But I only want to remove the listener for some of those elements, like this:

`$('body.off-canvas').off('mouseenter', '.has-tooltip.my-custom-class');`

It turns out jQuery will not recognize this as "subtractive" of the greater set of `.has-tooltip` elements, instead essentially saying, "There is no event listener matching this exact selector, therefore I will do nothing." Does anyone have a good workaround? I found some that will work if you're creating the original listener yourself, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: kinda going at this from a different angle,but maybe consider using `.filter()` method or `:not()` selector to filter out `.my-custom-class` before .`on()` is applied?

Comment: Thanks for the input; that would work if I were creating the original listener myself, but unfortunately it's part of a third party library. I suppose I could modify the library but I'd prefer not to since that wouldn't be very good practice.

Comment: so the library doesn't have ability to let you specify it in a config? that's a shame

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can stop event bubbling on those anchor links if you want to prevent that "mouseenter" function applied on body element from getting triggered.

Using JQUERY :

```
$(".has-tooltip.my-custom-class").on("mouseenter", function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   ....
   ....
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

I actually did try this. I don't know if it was a question of listener ordering or what, but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by taking a different approach. I had thought I couldn't remove the default Foundation events for all the normal tooltips because I needed Foundation to still build the tooltip elements. The workaround was tricky, but it got the job done.

I manually triggered the `mouseenter` event on *all* of the tooltips as soon as the page loaded, using a special CSS class to force them to stay invisible after being initialized instead of fading in. I had to simulate the mouse data in the event because Foundation depends on that to initially position the tooltips. Once the DOM modifications had been made, I could add listeners to the normal tooltips that mimic the default behavior while adding custom listeners to my customized elements.

```
// simulate and trigger default tooltip hover event to allow Foundation to create spans
$('body.off-canvas .has-tip').each(function(){
    var event = $.Event('mouseenter');

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var position = $(this).position();

    event.clientX = offset.left;
    event.clientY = offset.top;
    //event.offsetX = ;
    //event.offsetY = ;
    event.pageX = offset.left;
    event.pageY = offset.top;
    event.screenX = offset.left;
    //event.screenY = ;
    $(this).trigger(event);
});
$('body.off-canvas .has-tip').trigger('mouseleave');

// remove default events
$('body.off-canvas').off('mouseenter', '.has-tip');
$('body.off-canvas').off('mouseleave', '.has-tip');

// restore normal tooltips to normal behavior
$('body.off-canvas').on('mouseenter', '.has-tip:not(.has-details)', function(){
    $('span.tooltip[data-selector="' + $(this).data('selector') + '"]').removeClass('force-visibility-hidden').fadeIn();
});
$('body.off-canvas').on('mouseleave', '.has-tip:not(.has-details)', function(){
    $('span.tooltip[data-selector="' + $(this).data('selector') + '"]').fadeOut();
});

// set up custom details tooltip listener
$('body.off-canvas').on('mouseenter', '.has-tip.has-details', function(e){
    ...
});
```

As a side note, I also had to wrap the whole thing in a `setTimeout(..., 200);` to ensure that it would execute after the Foundation listeners had been applied.

All in all, this is one of the more convoluted pieces of code I've ever written, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stopImmediatePropagation()` to stop all other handlers on the element. Since the handlers are executed in the order they are added, so make sure to add your code **before** you add Zurb's code. Here is an example of how you can test for `my-custom-class`:

```
$(function(){
    $('body.off-canvas').on('mouseenter', '.has-tooltip', function(event){
        if($(event.target).hasClass('my-custom-class')){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    });
});
```